# Flex 3: Code-behind problem

Tags: flex3, code-behind

I have some VBox with button. I want my button changes the label after clicking on it. I'm trying to use the code-behind practice but the instance of the button is always null. There is code:

```
package TestPackage 
{
    import mx.containers.VBox;
    import mx.controls.Button;
    public class ControlsBox extends VBox 
    {
        [Bindable]
        public var btnPlay : Button;
        public function ControlsBox() 
        {
            super();
        }
        override protected function childrenCreated():void
        {
            super.childrenCreated();
        }
        public function ChangeImage():void
            {
                btnPlay.label = "a";
            }
    }
}

Here is mxml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    xmlns:controls="TestPackage.*">
<controls:ControlsBox id="ctrlVBox">
        <mx:Button id="btnPlay" click="this.ctrlVBox.ChangeImage();" label="c"></mx:Button>
</controls:ControlsBox>
</mx:Application>
```

What am I doing wrong? And how to do that properly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't do this very often in flex, but I think you want something like this:

```
<controls:ControlsBox id="ctrlVBox">
   <controls:btnPlay>
      <mx:Button click="this.ctrlVBox.ChangeImage();" label="c"></mx:Button>
   </controls:btnPlay>
</controls:ControlsBox>
```

Comment: Hmmm.... looks weird... I want to have a button and I want to have the opportunity to work with it from code-behind... In your code we should insert one button into the another one. I don't understand why... thanks anyway

Comment: The codebehind declares a *variable* `btnPlay` that can hold a instance of type `Button`, but the value of the variable is initially null - the codebehind does not actually create a Button instance. Instead, the button *instance* is created by the mxml statement `<mx:Button ..../>`.  The `Button`'s location within `<controls:btnPlay>` tells MXML to assign the new `Button` instance to the `btnPlay` variable.  Weird syntax, but it should work.

Comment: [Spark Skinning](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSC8DB0C28-F7A6-48ff-9899-7957415A0A49.html) is a much better fit for what you're trying to do -- it makes this kind of thing much easier than trying to shoehorn in the .NET "codebehind" concept.  Specifically, you might want to check out [Skin Parts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_skin_parts.html).